# Not able to create a directory in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 12.04. I am trying to run hbase. I have created another user hduser in another group & when I try to run start-hbase.sh, I get the following error -

```
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.18/bin/../logs': Permission denied
```

I also did

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/lib/hbase
```

Even then, I am getting the same error.

Comment: This should be asked on askubuntu.com, methinks.

Comment: Try sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/lib/hbase, although is a bit extreme

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you chmod a directories you dont change children directories. So, the command:

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/lib/hbase
```

will not change permissoins in:

```
/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.18/bin/../logs
```

To do chmod recursively you need to use the -R flag

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/lib/hbase
```

It may not be a good idea to give all permissions to everybody in that directory, but it will acomplish what you tried to do.